# ./fibonacci.sh: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `do'

Tags: linux, shell, fibonacci

Do you know what's wrong with my Fibonacci-Script, I get always the Error Message:
./fibonacci.sh: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `do'

```
#!/bin/bash
#fibonacci
echo "Geben Sie die n-te Fibonacci-Zahl ein:"
read n

if [$n -lt 2]; then
    echo $n
else
    array[0] = 0
    array[1] = 1
    for[k=2; $k -le $n; k++]; do
        x = $array[0] + $array[1]
        $array[0] = $array[1]
        $array[1] = $x
    done
    echo $array[1]
fi
```

Please help!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. As you are very new, you should have a look at the faq http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 2):

You had a few bugs inside.
First, improper use of arrays. use curly braces if you use them. See [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html). Second, I redesigned your code with a `while` loop - it is easier to understand. Third, bash doesn't like spaces in assignments.

```
#!/bin/bash
#fibonacci
echo "Geben Sie die n-te Fibonacci-Zahl ein:"
read n

if [ $n -lt 2 ]; then
    echo $n
else
    array[0]=0
    array[1]=1
    k=2
    while [ $k -le $n ]
    do
        let x=${array[0]}+${array[1]}
        array[0]=${array[1]}
        array[1]=$x
        let k=$k+1
    done
    echo ${array[1]}
fi
```

example:

```
$ ./test.sh 
Geben Sie die n-te Fibonacci-Zahl ein:
6
8
```